# Downloads throttled by Amazon AWS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've been gathering data from [SAMHDA](https://www.datafiles.samhsa.gov/study-dataset/national-household-survey-drug-abuse-1995-nhsda-1995-ds0001-nid13663) and I'm experiencing VERY SLOW download speeds, I'm talking <200kbps. Earlier, I tried downloading the files using a python script. Is it possible that my IP address has been blacklisted or something? If so, is there anything I can do to fix it?

Note: speeds are a little better on Firefox (ive been using chrome).

Answer (score 0):

The network bandwidth available to an Amazon EC2 instance depends upon the **Instance Type**.

Basically, smaller instances have lower bandwidth and larger instances have high bandwidth. The actual speeds are stated, but the bandwidth names (low, high) are displayed in the Amazon EC2 management console.

Therefore, try using a larger Instance Type -- it will give you more networking bandwidth.

Answer (score -1):

Amazon doesn't do that, and if they did they'd email you about it. Check the TOS of the data source (SAMHDA) you can try and debug by releasing your IP and getting a new one, but rotating IP to avoid throttling might be against TOS.